# monte carlo with PERT distribution EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, simulation, montecarlo

I have to provide a 1000 iteration monte-carlo simulation in EXCEL
We will use the PERT distribution for all of our randomly generated times.

Here my data. I calculated the expected time and variance
I generated the iterations from 1 to 1000 then I am stuck I do not know how to generate the 1000 iterations. I tried to use RANDBETWEEN but I am not sure what to consider min and max
Do you think I can use Most optimistic time as min and worst time as max ?

[image]

[image]